# ADFS not ending user session on SAML SLO

Tags: adfs

I have a Oracle Identity Federation integration with ADFS. I'm inspecting the SAML trafic and when triggering the SLO from OIF I get a successfull SAML SLO response answere answer back from ADFS.

When I try to start a new SSO session with ADFS I am not asked for username and password.

Does anyone have a clue on how to make ADFS do a real sign out if the user?

Answer (score 0):

When ADFS does send a response it normally clears the ADFS authentication session cookies. Which means that there is a new authentication is required. It really work, no doubt. 
What often happens is that Windows Integrated Logon automatically (without questions) logs the user on again. You will need a low level trace to see it.

Comment: In this case ADFS does not use windows logon(Kerberos), it only uses basic username passoword auth

Comment: If ADFS 2.0 or newer: Are the MSISAuth cookies cleared or not?